# How to make images act as checkboxes in an html form?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to create a form where users can select options, rather than using checkboxes, I want them to be able to select images.

When they select the images, they would likely have a border around them that shows they have been selected.

Which type of input handles this?

Comment: `img` tags with click handlers that toggles the borders around them will be fine.

Comment: How would they also be a part of a form? That seems like it does not work at all for this

Comment: based on the selection you can have hidden inputs whose values are modified.

Comment: Images might look cool, but practically everyone on the planet knows what check-boxes are and how they work.  Can you put a check-box next to an image?

Comment: Its for a homework assignment, so I just want to try to test myself

Answer (score 2):

Since checkboxes are the default HTML behaviour for selected/not selected, I would do it like this:

- Create a form
- For each image, add a checkbox next to it
- Name the images and checkboxes with a similar id (checkbox1/image1, checkbox2/image2, ...)
- Hide the checkboxes with Javascript
- Bind a Javascript event to each of the images to check/uncheck the checkbox associated with the image (can be done either using the ID or going by their position in the DOM)

This would have the added advantage that people with Javascript disabled would still be able to select images by clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use [buttons](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5). You can use background images that the user will see and you process the form with the values of the element.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery plugin, http://ajaxdump.com/?0BNm4jJ0

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

You can do it the other way around, using (only tested in chrome) `:before` and images:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/hG9Fh/

No, I did *not* just type all that CSS up off the top of my head `:D`

CSS, this code was built purely for Chrome and is not cross-browser compatible in any way:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #ededed 38%, #dedede);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08),
      inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  color: #444;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  bottom: 2px;
  height: 13px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 13px;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked::before {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

:enabled:hover:input[type='checkbox'] {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0f0f0, #f0f0f0 38%, #e0e0e0);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
      inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  color: black;
}

:enabled:active:input[type='checkbox'] {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #e7e7e7 38%, #d7d7d7);
  box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}

input:disabled:[type='checkbox'] {
  opacity: .75;
}

:enabled:focus:input[type='checkbox'] {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 200ms;
  border-color: rgb(77, 144, 254);
  outline: none;
}​
```

### Solution 2

Replace the checkboxes with images that trigger them onclick, a good article on that is here: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/